# Spa Drain vs Spa Fill?

Tags: pool

I've just moved into a house with a pool and spa, and I'm trying to understand some terminology; in particular the meaning and operation of **SPA DRAIN** and **SPA FILL** (and whether my equipment might have been set up backwards).

So, control is via an AquaLink RS panel of some sort. Among umpteen buttons, two are labelled **SPA DRAIN** and one **SPA FILL**. Their respective descriptions are as follows:

- **SPA DRAIN** Intake valve rotates so intake is from spa. Return valve remains in pool position so return is to the pool. With the filter pump on, water is drawn from the spa and pumped into the pool.
- **SPA FILL** Intake valve rotates so intake is from pool. Return valve rotates so return is to spa. With the filter pump on, pool water is pumped into the spa.

As I read those, my expectation is as follows:

- if I press **SPA DRAIN** then I should see the spa water level **FALL**
- if I press **SPA FILL** then I should see the spa water level **RISE**

But I am seeing exactly the opposite. To get the spa water level to rise (and eventually spill back over into the pool as a wee waterfall), I need to press **SPA DRAIN**, which seems counterintuitive given the above descriptions.

Am I reading it wrong, and getting my *"intake...from"* and *"return...to"* directions wrong? Or is it possible the whole thing has been configured backwards?

Comment: Quite possible it's backward. May not be worth fixing except by changing the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to talk to the person who installed the pool and plumbing. He was surprised to hear what I told him, and he confirmed that he must have installed it backwards. Or rather, he must set the pumps — they must have some kind of “polarity” switch - backwards. So the fix is simple and, given that I now know that for this installation fill means drain, and drain means fill, not even strictly necessary.